# 1/2" drywall ceiling support 7lb ceiling-mounted speakers?

Tags: drywall, speakers, audio

I recently purchase some JBL SP8II wall-mount speakers that I would actually like to use in the ceilings. However these speakers don't come with a between-the-studs support of any kind (there is a wall bracket but it's a flimsy plastic that wouldn't add any support for a ceiling mount situation).

Do you think my 1/2" drywall ceilings would support these 7lb speakers without creating sag? The installation instructions are basically to cut out a 8"x10" rectangular hole in the drywall and then put the speakers in that hole, mounting them to the drywall.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How deep are the speakers? What mounting mechanism is included?

Comment: Are you sure your drywall is half inch? It's only in recent years that the new half-inch "no sag" drywall has come into fashion. 5/8 has much more stiffness to it, and I wouldn't hesitate to mount to that.

Comment: why are you posting this question twice?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely not hang something that heavy on the ceiling without anchoring it into a rafter. The constant weight will inevitably cause the ceiling to sag, especially if is only 1/2" drywall.

I would advise adding more wood framing between the rafters and mounting the speaker to that.

Do you have a picture of the speaker and mounting bracket?

Comment: Rafters?  ---> Joists?

Comment: My bad ;) I get it confused because its all kind of the same piece usually.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in that I would not want to rely on the drywall in the ceiling to mount these.  Would it be possible to use a retrofit ceiling fan mount that is designed to span between rafters?  You would likely have to remove the box designed to hold the ceiling fan, but perhaps you could use the arm portion and mount the speaker enclosure to it?  They are cheap (around $15) and readily available at most home improvement stores.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends how the speakers are connected to the drywall. When we do commercial ceiling installs, there is a metal frame behind the speaker and drywall, and the speaker mounts from the front so that there's a sandwich of drywall (or, in our case, ceiling tile) in the middle. That way, the load on the ceiling is spread out quite a bit.

If you can't get the mounting frames, you can always make something from wood or plywood to mount the speaker into - spreading the load away from just the speaker is essential. If you do that, you shouldn't have any issues with well mounted drywall.